# Never-ending instances of CTCall

Tags: ios

So I found this code snippet online to detect calls coming in. Works great except it continuously creates CTCall objects which are never released. This in turn consumes a pretty large amount of memory.

I'm not familiar enough with block statements to properly analyze what's going on so I was hoping to get some help. What would I need to do here to remove the CTCall objects.

The below code is in my AppDelegate in the application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
__block NSString *lastState = nil;

__block void (^block)(void) = ^(void) {

    CTCall *call = [[callCenter currentCalls] anyObject];

    if (call) {

        if (![lastState isEqualToString:call.callState]) {

            self.isInCall = YES;
            lastState = call.callState;
            [self postNotificationWithBody:call.callState];
        }

    } else {

        if (lastState != nil) {

            [self postNotificationWithBody:@"CTCallStateDisconnected"];
            self.isInCall = NO;

        } else {

            if (self.isInCall) {

                int64_t delayInSeconds = 3.0;
                dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
                dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

                    [self postNotificationWithBody:@"Call Failed"];
                });

                self.isInCall = NO;
            }
        }
        lastState = nil;
    }

    int64_t delayInSeconds = 0.1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);

};

block();
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated. I'm also getting a warning at the end. "Capturing 'block' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle"

This may be part of the problem, but like I mentioned above. I'm not so good with block statements. So I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something...if it's simply executed in-line after being assigned, why is it a block at all?

Comment: Your right, there's no need for a block so I removed it and put everything in its own method. I believe that the problem is in the line CTCall *call = [[self.callCenter currentCalls] anyObject]; I looked at the Apple docs and it states that the object returned by currentCalls is retained. Where and how should I be releasing that?

Comment: If you're still trying to identify memory usage problems, I'd suggest using Instruments with its Allocations template.  That can give you a history of objects that are in memory and let you trace retain/release activity to see where it's not happening the way you expect.

Comment: That's what I was doing. Looking at All Heap Allocations indicates that CTCall is allocated repeatedly and looks like it is never being released.

Comment: That's odd.  `CTCall *call` is local scope and `anyObject` shouldn't give you ownership of what it returns.  ...and, for that matter, it's not like `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: ` is called multiple times.  What does the stack trace look like in Instruments for the creation of the `CTCall` objects?

Comment: dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) { [self detectCalls]}; is called repeatedly so that when callCenter returns a CTCall object, I can perform the proper action. This is detecting incoming calls with the app running in the background btw.

Comment: The detectCalls method is a new method I created to move all the code that was previously in a block to. I then call this method from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and then the method is called repeatedly from the dispatch_after method